# Que tengo mal en este codigo de java?

Tags: java, array, class

Tengo este código y no entiendo el error que me salta alguien me ayuda? pls

El código tiene que en la primera opción me deje hacer un vector 3x3 y en la opción 2 darme el vector que escribí

y si también me pueden dar una idea de como hacer para ordenar el vector de forma descendente y hacer que se invierta

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arreglo{
  
  public static void main(String args[]){
  Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int M[][] = new int[3][3];
    int opc, i, j;
    do {
      System.out.println("Menu");
      System.out.println("1. Cargar");
      System.out.println("2. Imprimir");
      System.out.println("3. Salir");
      System.out.println("Digite opcion");
      opc = entrada.nextInt();

      switch(opc){
        case 1: cargar(M);
        break;

        case 2: imprimir(M);
        break;
       }
      } while(opc != 3);
     }

  public static void cargar(int M[][]){
    System.out.println("Digite datos \n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < M[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println("M[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
        M[i][j] = entrada.nextInt();
      }
    }
   }
 
  public static void imprimir(int M[][]){
    System.out.println("Los datos cargados son \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.println(M[i][j] + "\t");
       }
      System.out.println("\n");
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Declara la variable entrada como un atributo de la clase para que los métodos puedan acceder a ella.Eso solucionará tu error. Checa https://onlinegdb.com/wajugDG2F

Comment: En cuanto a la ordenación, debes ser más específico. Una matriz de 3x3 se puede ordenar por filas, por columnas, por el valor de sus elementos a nivel global, etc.. ¿Cuál es el criterio de ordenación? Cuando te refieres a inversión, ¿a qué te refieres? ¿A la matriz inversa? ¿Al recíproco de cada elemento? ¿A cambiar de signo cada elemento? ¿ A invertir los elementos por la diagonal principal? ¿Por la diagonal secundaria? Checa [como preguntar.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Las preguntas deben ser concretas y tener de manera explícita y reproducible los errores.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.